# Get the Spinner Value from Activity into my adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, spinner, fragmentpageradapter

I have a Spinner set in my Toolbar in my Activity.
In my activity I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which I populate with five `Pages`, from a `newInstance` of a Fragment.
How can I get the value of my spinner after I change it into my fragments. I'm using this spinner to set a Single/Multi Selection Mode in the `RecyclerView` I have in my fragment Pages.
I know how to get the value in my activity even to pass it to the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, but my problem is if I change it, for it to take effect in my `RecyclerView` I have to reload the Activity.

My Activity

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pattern_selector);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        patternImages = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(PATTERN_IMAGES);
        patternSelectedMode = intent.getIntExtra(PATTERN_SELECTED_MODE, 0);
        titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs_pattern_title);
//        spinnerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_pattern_selector);
        setUpPagerAdapter();
        setUpToolbar();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pattern_selector, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View mainContent = findViewById(R.id.view_pager_container);
        if (mainContent != null) {
            mainContent.setAlpha(0);
            mainContent.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(MAIN_CONTENT_FADE_IN_DURATION);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No view with ID main_content to fade in.");
        }
    }

    private void setUpPagerAdapter() {

        patternsPagerAdapter = new PatternsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    minIndex = 0;
                    maxIndex = 3;
                    fragmentTitle = titles[i];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    minIndex = 3;
                    maxIndex = 50;
                    fragmentTitle = titles[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    minIndex = 50;
                    maxIndex = 60;
                    fragmentTitle = titles[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    minIndex = 60;
                    maxIndex = 86;
                    fragmentTitle = titles[i];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    minIndex = 0;
                    maxIndex = 0;
                    fragmentTitle = titles[i];
                    break;
            }
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(MIN_NUMBERS, minIndex);
            bundle.putInt(MAX_NUMBERS, maxIndex);
            bundle.putInt(PATTERN_SELECTED_MODE, patternSelectedMode);
            bundle.putString(TITLE, fragmentTitle);
            patternsPagerAdapter.addFragment(FragmentCommonPatterns.newInstance(minIndex, maxIndex, fragmentTitle, patternSelectedMode));
        }
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_container);
        viewPager.setAdapter(patternsPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pattern_tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            //TODO Check if I need this
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                patternsPagerAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition());
//                System.out.println("Fragment Selected " + tab.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

//                System.out.println("Fragment Deselected " + tab.getText().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

//                System.out.println("Fragment Reselected " + tab.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }

    public void setUpToolbar() {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pattern_selector);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_pattern_selector, R.layout.item_spinner_pattern_selector);
        spinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        toolbar.addView(spinner, 0);
        spinner.setSelection(patternSelectedMode);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        patternSelectedMode = 1;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.pattern_image_selected_single), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for (PatternImages current : patternImages) {
                            current.setSelected(false);
                        }
                        patternsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        patternSelectedMode = 2;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.pattern_image_selected_multiple), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        patternsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    default:
                        patternSelectedMode = 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<PatternImages> getPatternImages() {

        return patternImages;
    }
    public int getSpinnerValue() {

        return patternSelectedMode;
    }

    public void setPattern(MenuItem item) {

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PATTERN_IMAGES, patternImages);
        returnIntent.putExtra(PATTERN_SELECTED_MODE, patternSelectedMode);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.out_right);

    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
//        spinner.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.get_attention));
//        Log.d(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged Started");
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() > 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() - 1);
        } else {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PATTERN_IMAGES, patternImages);
            returnIntent.putExtra(PATTERN_SELECTED_MODE, patternSelectedMode);
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.out_right);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Fragment

```
 public static FragmentCommonPatterns newInstance(int minIndex, int maxIndex, String fragmentTitle, int patternSelectedMode) {

    FragmentCommonPatterns patterns = new FragmentCommonPatterns();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MIN_NUMBERS, minIndex);
    args.putInt(MAX_NUMBERS, maxIndex);
    args.putInt(PATTERN_SELECTED_MODE, patternSelectedMode);
    args.putString(TITLE, fragmentTitle);
    patterns.setArguments(args);
    return patterns;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    minIndex = getArguments().getInt(MIN_NUMBERS);
    maxIndex = getArguments().getInt(MAX_NUMBERS);
    fragmentTitle = getArguments().getString(TITLE);
    titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs_pattern_title);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_common_patterns, container, false);
    if (fragmentTitle.equals(titles[4])) {
        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_custom_patterns);
        floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit your own custom patterns", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //TODO
            }
        });
    }
    ActivityPatternSelector activityPatternSelector = (ActivityPatternSelector) getActivity();
    patternImages = activityPatternSelector.getPatternImages();
    patternSelectedMode=activityPatternSelector.getSpinnerValue();
    setUpPatternsRecyclerView(view);
    return view;
}

private void setUpPatternsRecyclerView(View view) {

    RecyclerView recyclerPatternsView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pattern_image_recycler_view);
    PatternImageAdapter adapter = new PatternImageAdapter(getActivity(), patternImages.subList(minIndex, maxIndex), patternSelectedMode);
    recyclerPatternsView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ColumnQty columnQty = new ColumnQty(getActivity(), R.layout.item_image_pattern_cardview);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), columnQty.calculateNoOfColumns());
    recyclerPatternsView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerPatternsView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerPatternsView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerPatternsView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacing(columnQty.calculateSpacing()));
}
```

Comment: Post the full code of your Activity.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an "updatePattern" method to your fragment.

Then iterate over the fragments in your adapter and update them.

**Pseudo code:**

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < fragmentsArray.size() ; i ++) {
            Fragment fragment = fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(i);
            fragment.updateSelectedPatternMode(newPattern);
 }
```

*PS*: For cleanred code you can encapsulate the iterating over fragments inside your PagerAdapter and add a public update method to the adapter.

Comment: I do like your idea @mrsegev, but made think of resetting the `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead, which is what I did, and basically works, does what I want, but does not solve my question though. Just wonder if is the way to go in terms of efficiency. I call `setUpPagerAdapter()` in the three cases of my spinner, it reset my PagerAdapter and I can use ViewPager to reset it to a previous position.
Thank you, +1 for the idea.

Comment: Interesting solution! Actually, In term of efficiency, I believe updating the fragments directly would be more efficient because each time your selection changes only the relevant code inside the fragment would be called without forcing the whole pager to recreate itself. (Similar to RecyclerView payloads in some way?)

Comment: In the end, found out that what I was doing was totally wrong, I was stacking `ViewPager` over `ViewPager`, for me it was ok, but not optimal(I mean the purpose of the spinner is not to choose values forever :-D). Ended up applying your answer and implementing Interfaces here and there. Thank you for your comments.